# OpenCL - clCreateBuffer size error. Possible work arounds?

Tags: c, memory, opencl

After investigating the reason why my program was crashing, I found that I was hitting the maximum for a buffer size, which is 512Mb for me `(CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE)`.

In my case, here are the parameters.

```
P = 146 (interpolation factor)
num_items = 918144 (number of samples)
sizeof(float) -> 4
```

So my clCreateBuffer looks something like this:

```
output = clCreateBuffer(
        context,
        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
        num_items * P * sizeof(float),
        NULL,
        &status);
```

When the above is multiplied together and divided by (1024x1024), you get around 511Mb which is under the threshold. Change any of the parameters to one higher now and it crashes because it will exceed that 512 value.

My questions is, **how can I implement the code in a way where I can use block sizes to do my calculations instead of storing everything in memory and passing that massive chunk of data to the kernel?** In reality, the number of samples I have could easily vary to **over 5 million** and I **definitely** will not have enough memory to store all those values.

I'm just not sure how to pass small sets of values into my kernel as I have three steps that the values go though before getting an output.

First is an interpolation kernel, then the values go to a lowpass filter kernel and then to a kernel that does decimation. After that the values are written to an output array. If further details of the program are needed for the sake of the problem I can add more.

**UPDATE**
Not sure what the expected answer is here, if anyone has a reason I would love to hear it and potentially accept it as the valid answer. I don't work with OpenCL anymore so i don't have the setup to verify.

Comment: What platform are you using? AMD/Intel/Nvidia?

Comment: What I'm getting at with my question is GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT:  
https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/2737/some-cards-need-export-gpu-max-alloc-percent-95

Comment: @mfa sorry forgot to mention, i'm using an ATI Firepro v5800 (AMD).

Comment: I tried using `setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 95` and `setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1` but it still crashes.

Comment: Try to export/set this environment variable: GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=95  a lot of AMD setups default to 25 or 50% by default. you should be able to get ~972MB using that card @95% allocaiton.

Comment: Is there any way to confirm that I have set it successfully?

Comment: Edit: So it does say specified value was saved. But it still does crash on the same issue where I am hitting 515Mb instead of 512. I am using gDEbugger to read the error codes

Comment: You should be able to see the new value for CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE form within your app. Beyond this variable, I don't have any other ideas right now.

Comment: After displaying the value, it still shows 536870912. If we divide that by (1024x1024) it still comes down to 512Mb. Not sure if 512 is the limit or if something else is going on

Comment: I think that is the root of your problem, but I don't have a more specific answer to offer you. If you do figure it out, could you post it here as an answer please? I'm sure other's have the same question.

Comment: For sure. For now I am using a smaller file size to make it work. But some sort of memory management system will have to be implemented. I might try making a buffer that stores 8Mb at a time, does the computation and repeats until the file that it is reading from is complete. If I end up getting this to work I will post it for sure. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: maybe it's a problem with that hardware / driver. have you tried on a different device with more available memory?

Comment: I don't have one that's readily available. I just ordered a nVidia 1080, so i'll update with the results when it comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [OpenCL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_API.html#_buffer_objects) and `clCreateBuffer` I would say the solution here is *allowing* use of host memory by adding `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` to `flags` (or whatever suits your use case). Paragraphs from `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`:

> This flag is valid only if host_ptr is not NULL. If specified, it
> indicates that the application wants the OpenCL implementation to use
> memory referenced by host_ptr as the storage bits for the memory
> object.
>
> The contents of the memory pointed to by host_ptr at the time
> of the clCreateBuffer call define the initial contents of the buffer
> object.
>
> **OpenCL implementations are allowed to cache the buffer
> contents pointed to by host_ptr in device memory. This cached copy can
> be used when kernels are executed on a device.**

What this means is the driver will pass memory between host and device in the most efficient way it can. Basically what you propose yourself in comments, except it is already built into the driver, activated with a single flag, and probably more efficient than anything you can come up with.